# TinyMCE editor in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, wysiwyg

I created following an asp.net page with tiny editor. It is Ok, good work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options 
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave", 
        setup: function(ed) { ed.onKeyPress.add( function(ed, evt) { } );},

        // Theme options 
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor", 
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen", 
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft", 
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top", 
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left", 
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS) 
        content_css: "css/content.css", 

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs 
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js", 
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js", 
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js", 
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js", 

        // Style formats 
        style_formats: [ 
            { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' }, 
            { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} }, 
            { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} }, 
            { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' }, 
            { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' }, 
            { title: 'Table styles' }, 
            { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' } 
        ] 

    // Replace values for the template plugin 
    //template_replace_values: { username: "zanhtet", staffid: "991234" } 
    }); 
</script>
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%" runat="server"></textarea>
```

And then I have added a following new textarea in this page.

```
<textarea id="elm2" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%" runat="server">
```

At that time, the tinyMCE editor is two. I want to be one tiny editor and one textarea. How could I do that? Please, help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the specific id of your textarea so only one textarea becomes a editor.
Do this:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
            ...
            elements : "elm1,elm2"
    });
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:elements